# Pulling data from one Table ... manipulating that data, then sending to a different table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, logic

Attempting to have the output of this code fill a database from the results of an IF LOOP pulling data from a separate database. Here's what I have so far... I know it's off.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY      OFF

DECLARE
    v_idno          donorbackup.idno%TYPE :=&input_idno;
    v_yrgoal        donorbackup.yrgoal%TYPE;
    v_newgoal       donorbackup.yrgoal%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT yrgoal INTO v_yrgoal
    FROM   donorbackup
    WHERE  idno = v_idno;

    IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
        v_newgoal :=  v_yrgoal * 2 ;
    ELSE
        v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 1.5;
    END IF;

    UPDATE amttopay <-- Would I even be updating this table like this?
    SET    amt = v_newgoal
    WHERE  idno = v_idno;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET VERIFY ON
```

I'm trying to take the output from the IF and breaking it into 3 separate results. Not even sure how to begin.

It should look like this at the end:

```
REC_NO    IDNO     YRGOAL
001       11111    333.333
002       11111    333.333
003       11111    333.333
```

That output would be the result of a user entering '11111' at the prompt, it then matches with data from another table and (in this case) finds the yrgoal is equal to 500, so it doubles it. Next it would insert that information 3x with the same IDNO, yrgoal divided by 3. and I'm assuming the rec_no would just be sequenced as to count the outputs.

Here is my updated code, been trying to figure this out for 2 days now.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET VERIFY      OFF
ACCEPT in_idno PROMPT 'Enter desired IDNO: ';

DECLARE
    v_idno          donorbackup.idno%TYPE :='&in_idno';
    v_yrgoal        donorbackup.yrgoal%TYPE;
    v_newgoal       donorbackup.yrgoal%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT idno INTO v_idno
    FROM   donorbackup
    WHERE  idno = v_idno;

    IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
        v_newgoal :=  v_yrgoal * 2 ;
        INSERT INTO amttopay
        VALUES ('&in_idno', v_newgoal);
    ELSE
        v_newgoal := v_yrgoal * 1.5 ;
        INSERT INTO amttopay
        VALUES ('&in_idno', v_newgoal);
    END IF;
END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF
SET VERIFY ON
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "breaking into 3 separate results". What is the criteria for each result? Also provide sample input and output values.

Comment: @Belayer I hope that makes more sense, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you're calculating an annual value (`v_newgoal`) then creating a periodic value for each period. In this case #periods = 3. Thus each row has value of `v_newgoal/3`. You almost have a workable solution. You just need to adjust the periodic value then insert n rows. But I would bring the insert outside of the if statement, so:

```
IF v_yrgoal > 500 THEN
   v_newgoal := (v_yrgoal * 2) / 3 ;
ELSE
   v_newgoal := (v_yrgoal * 1.5) / 3 ;
END IF ; 

FOR i in 1 .. 3 LOOP
    INSERT INTO amttopay
    VALUES('&in_idno', v_newgoal);
END LOOP;
```

This is not the best implementation, but it seems to match your stated requirement.

BTW: Check out the FOR construct.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, you have no idea how much you helped me. One question though, Everything seems to work after I tweaked it a tiny bit, how could I make it so the 'rec_n' field counts as fields are entered? Would I use a sequence? If so how would I initialize it into the program?

Comment: @JBen, that depends on the requirement. Maybe you could just use `i` from the loop. If you want to use a sequence, create it separately with `create sequence mysequence;` and then just refer to `mysequence.nextval` wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain SQL:

```
insert into amttopay
     ( idno, seq, goal )
select idno
     , amttopay_seq.nextval
     , yrgoal * case when yrgoal > 500 then 2 else 1.5 end / 3 as goal
from   donorbackup
       cross join (select dummy from dual connect by rownum <= 3) rowtrebler
where  idno = &donor_id;
```

The only fancy part is the `rowtrebler` inline view that's just there to generate three dummy rows, so that when I cross join it to `donorbackup` I get the result three times instead of once.

I suppose you could avoid hardcoding the `3` in two places to make it a bit more robust in case you ever needed to change it, though maybe this is overkill:

```
insert into amttopay
     ( idno, seq, goal )
select idno
     , amttopay_seq.nextval
     , yrgoal * case when yrgoal > 500 then 2 else 1.5 end / split.numrows as goal
from   donorbackup d
       cross join (select count(*) over() as numrows from dual connect by rownum <= 5) split
where  idno = &donor_id;
```